# How do I save data in firebase with localId

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save data in firebase with a local Id .At the moment a local id child is not generated in firebase.Can someone please point out what I am missing in my code.

```
  browser = request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
  data = {"browser": browser}

  database.child("browser").child('localId').child("details").set(data)
  return render(request, "home.html", {"e": email})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new child node under a location with the Firebase Admin SDK for Python, you should call the [`push()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.db#firebase_admin.db.Reference.push). Something like this:

```
database.child("browser").push({ 'details': data })
```

I also highly recommend reading the blog post [Accessing Database from the Python Admin SDK](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/accessing-database-from-python-admin-sdk.html).